# How do you equip items in Zelda: Skyward Sword?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

How do you fill a bottle in Skyward Sword?  I'm trying to scoop up some water, and I can't figure out how to get the bottle equipped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can equip it like anything else in your bag, such as when you've got a new shield (hold <kbd>-</kbd> to select, press <kbd>-</kbd> to get it out.) and use it like an item. (Press <kbd>A</kbd> to use it after equiping.)

Comment: "A" just gives me the description.  "You can put potions and other things in this handy bottle."  It doesn't seem to equip it.

Comment: You equip it first, then press A to use it.

Comment: -1: There's an assumption the user knows how to equip "anything else in your bag"

Answer (score 3):

Finally figured it out.

Push and hold "-" and it will bring up a screen with all of your items in your pouch.  You then use the wii-mote to select the item that you would like to equip by pressing 'A' and you can use it like any other item.

Comment: Just to clarify for people who are stuck at the use stage, you might want to add "*press A* to use it like any other item"

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify: to equip items, you have to press <kbd>-</kbd> (minus) when you're **on the main walking-around screen**, not when you're on the inventory screen (which you can separately access by pressing <kbd>1</kbd> [one]). It's confusing because there is *also* a pouch in the middle of the inventory, which you can *also* interact with using the <kbd>-</kbd> (minus) button.

Answer (score 1):

Hold <kbd>-</kbd> then mouseover the desired item to equip (shield or bottle; medals are considered equipped if Link is carrying one and bags provide a passive storage bonus). Note that you don't have to equip a bottle to catch a fairy, you can use the Bug Catching Net instead.

To scoop up water, equip a bottle then press <kbd>A</kbd> while standing in the water.

Comment: The symbol in your first `kbd` isn't rendering properly. You might want to replace it with an image or something so that it shows up the same universally.

Comment: @AnnaLear How weird. Are you seeing the unrecognized glyph symbol or the missing glyph symbol? You may want to see if there is a font update for your OS or install a general purpose unicode font. [Wikipedia has a list of free unicode fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software_Unicode_typefaces) you can use to update.

Comment: It's doubly weird cause it's working now (same machine/browser). Before it just showed a square instead.

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you just used a regular dash to represent the minus button instead of the circled one.  Looking at it, it's not very obvious that it is supposed to represent it.

Comment: @AnnaLear I changed from raw unicode to HTML entity.

Answer (score 1):

If you are carrying the "Cursed Medal" in your pouch your pouch items are inaccessible. You must store the cursed medal at the claim check in the bazaar on skyloft.